# OneDrive Authentication & Shared URL access

Tags: onedrive

Couple of questions:

I implemented the authentication process with OneDrive. My desktop application is designed for end-users. Every time the application is launched the little browser window pops up asking the user to confirm access...and if more than 1 hour passed user needs to provide username and password. Is there any way that end-user with SOME SORT of saved credentials (or user Code +user Secret, or API code + API secret) will be able to invoke the application and not be prompted by browser form (that currently requires login - if access token expired - or confirmation)?

The goal of my application is file sharing - that is, one end user may send URL (to the file that he uploaded to OneDrive) to another user and the latter should be able to download the file by clicking on the link (without any prompts, exactly like in manual process of sharing link to the file in OneDrive). Is it possible? If yes, how to achieve that? That is, how do I get that URL? Redandent to say that I am looking for a programmatic way to obtain a URL that will achieve the above described)

Answer (score 2):

The OneDrive authentication process uses Microsoft account, which supports OAuth 2.0.   You should be able to point the user to:

https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=SCOPE&response_type=code&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI

Once the user authenticated and authorizes your app, the user will be taken to REDIRECT_URI/?code=CODE, where your app can exchange that code for an access token at:

https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=CODE&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI.

There are more details at http://onedrive.github.io/auth/msa_oauth.htm.